# Why is the finite complement Topology Minimal $T_1$

Tags: general-topology

Why is the finite complement Topology Minimal $T_1$. This seem the case as if I try to find any $T_1$ topology on a set X, then the finite complement topology always contained in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space, then the following are equivalent:

- $(X, \tau)$ is $T_1$
- all points $\{x\}$ are closed
- all finite subsets of $X$ are closed
- all complement of finite sets are open.

Comment: all complement of finite set are open in what topology ?

Comment: All open, closed are with respect to $\tau$. @Illustionist